# How to get the subset dataframe from the dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe(df):

```
         id  CI    VaR
0        1  0.600  1000
1        1  0.650  1100
2        1  0.700  1200
3        1  0.750  1300
4        2  0.600  2500
5        2  0.650  2600
6        2  0.700  2700
7        2  0.750  2800
8        3  0.600  1500
9        3  0.650  1600
10       3  0.700  1700
11       3  0.750  1800
```

i have to create a subset dataframe from this dataframe
im doing this;

```
for col in range(1,4):
    df2 = df1.loc[df1["id"]==col]
    print(df2)
```

output:

```
         id  CI    VaR
0        1  0.600  1000
1        1  0.650  1100
2        1  0.700  1200
3        1  0.750  1300
```

and

```
4        2  0.600  2500
5        2  0.650  2600
6        2  0.700  2700
7        2  0.750  2800
```

and

```
8        3  0.600  1500
9        3  0.650  1600
10       3  0.700  1700
11       3  0.750  1800
```

this will give me separate dataframe for id 1,2,3
Now i want to VaR value of all dataframe(1 ,2 and 3) and add all the value in the order they are and append to the dataframe of respective.
like:

```
obj = 0
for col in range(1,4):
    df2 = df1.loc[df1["id"]==col]
    obj = obj + df1["VaR"] # error is here
    print(df2)
```

But this is not working for me

i need ouput like ;

```
         id  CI    VaR   capital
0        1  0.600  1000  5000
1        1  0.650  1100  5300
2        1  0.700  1200  5600
3        1  0.750  1300  5900
```

capital value 5000 came from adding 1000 + 2500 + 1500 ( these are all first value of respecti id)
capital value 5300 came from adding 1100 + 2600 + 1600 ( these are all second value of respecti id)
and so on ...
and i need for all the id's
like;

```
4        2  0.600  2500   5000
5        2  0.650  2600   5300
6        2  0.700  2700   5600
7        2  0.750  2800   5900
```

and

```
8        3  0.600  1500   5000
9        3  0.650  1600   5300
10       3  0.700  1700   5600
11       3  0.750  1800   5900
```

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `groupby` with `transform`:

```
df['capital'] = df.groupby(df.groupby('id').cumcount())['VaR'].transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
  id    CI   VaR  capital
0    1  0.60  1000     5000
1    1  0.65  1100     5300
2    1  0.70  1200     5600
3    1  0.75  1300     5900
4    2  0.60  2500     5000
5    2  0.65  2600     5300
6    2  0.70  2700     5600
7    2  0.75  2800     5900
8    3  0.60  1500     5000
9    3  0.65  1600     5300
10   3  0.70  1700     5600
11   3  0.75  1800     5900
```

Details:

- First, groupby 'id' and `cumcount` to get position in each group
- Then, groupby "position" and sum with `transform`
- pandas  will  handle  aligning  values using indexes

Comment: @MichaelScofield You're welcome.  Happy  coding!  Be safe and stay healthy.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I've understood your question right. If you need to repeat the firt, second, third... sums of values in each group:

```py
vals = df.groupby(df.groupby("id").cumcount())["VaR"].sum()
df["capital"] = [*vals] * df["id"].nunique()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    id    CI   VaR  capital
0    1  0.60  1000     5000
1    1  0.65  1100     5300
2    1  0.70  1200     5600
3    1  0.75  1300     5900
4    2  0.60  2500     5000
5    2  0.65  2600     5300
6    2  0.70  2700     5600
7    2  0.75  2800     5900
8    3  0.60  1500     5000
9    3  0.65  1600     5300
10   3  0.70  1700     5600
11   3  0.75  1800     5900
```

Comment: You could also do `df['id'].nunique()` instead of `len(df["id"].unique())`

Answer (score 2):

An option via [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy-tile) and a different way to divide the DataFrame via [`np.arraysplit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy-array-split):

(Assumption: All id groups are equal length, and the total number of groups is equal to the number of rows per group)

```
from pprint import pprint

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'CI': [0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75],
    'VaR': [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 1500, 1600, 1700,
            1800]
})

unique_count = df['id'].nunique()
df['capital'] = np.tile(
    df.groupby(df.groupby("id").cumcount())["VaR"].sum(),
    unique_count
)

dfs = np.array_split(df, unique_count)

pprint(dfs)
```

`dfs`:

```
[   id    CI   VaR  capital
0   1  0.60  1000     5000
1   1  0.65  1100     5300
2   1  0.70  1200     5600
3   1  0.75  1300     5900,
    id    CI   VaR  capital
4   2  0.60  2500     5000
5   2  0.65  2600     5300
6   2  0.70  2700     5600
7   2  0.75  2800     5900,
     id    CI   VaR  capital
8    3  0.60  1500     5000
9    3  0.65  1600     5300
10   3  0.70  1700     5600
11   3  0.75  1800     5900]
```